# Error processing JSON content in JSON Extractor, message: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Malicious payload,

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-400, azure-load-testing

I am facing this error in the Azure Load Testing using jmeter scripts (.jmx files)
[Error Screenshot from the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlxZd.png)

When running The Azure Load Tests with the .jmx file, it was working fine for a while but suddenly got the error stated above (error status code of 400) for a PUT API call. It seems to only occur for large responses, especially the ones including JSONs with multiple nesting levels.

The same setup seems to still work fine in my local setup and is only failing via Azure.

I have tried to sanitize this malicious payload via Groovy code in the JSR223 Preprocessor with no results.

Please, kindly assist in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather report it to [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/) if it happens only in Azure.

The workarounds I can think of are:

1. Switch to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
2. Switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). See [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) article for details.

If you need help on this you will need to provide your JSON response and indicate which data you want to extract from there.

Comment: I have used the JSON JMESPAth Extractor instead of JSON Extractor and the issue got solved. Thanks!